# How to Create Windows 7 Theme dynamically according to the native computer screen resolution

Tags: windows-7, themes

If you ever pay attention to the default Windows 7 Theme build in, those themes will have a perfect image screen resolution no matter what size of the screen your device is on. It looks perfect on the Netbook, if you switch to a 27' inch monitor it too looks fantastic.

The default theme is located in

> C:\Windows\Resources\Themes

and if you ever bother to look into the file, those themes is calling a dll to somehow adjust those images according to your native screen size. (lets use Landscapes as an example)

> %SystemRoot%\Web\Wallpaper\Landscapes\

The image of the Landscapes theme is located above, but you will realize the image are perfect match to your current screen resolution.

That's probably why of course all the default themes looks good across all type of devices.

Now my question is how can I create a Windows 7 Theme that does those **dynamic screen resolutions adjustments depending on the current resolution** of the computer into just one Windows 7 Theme pack. (I know how to create a Windows 7 Theme, please don't tell me how I can do that)

Comment: The images in the Landscapes folder are 1920x1200 for me. Is there a problem just making your images the same resolution because obviously they chose a image resolution that works well with a lot of different desktop resolutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to. Windows resizes the files and saves a copy for you. But, just like anything, it needs

Windows has been resizing wallpapers since the Windows 3.0 days.

Give it  good source file. Just in case, I went to the horse's mouth.  Microsof't Net.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773190(v=vs.85).aspx

Nothing special here. Windows creates these wallpapers dynamically for you in the theme packs.  In fact, download one of Microsoft's theme packs.  It's just a compressed container, so rename it to *.zip and 
open it up.  Just really good jpgs (500K).

Comment: guess there is no way to do it the way I would imagined. but I will take that, thanks for the link. Good help !

Comment: Ya, pretty much include a decent res photo and Windows sizes it for you.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite impossible to do this with how the theme files work. As I said in the comment Microsoft chose images that work well in ANY resolution. Your best bet is to either have more than one theme or use a script to switch the images.

There is someone on the [sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/themes-styles/110213-theme-image-file-based-resolution.html) who actually did this with a script. This might be your best bet.

Comment: yeah Thanks for that, providing multiple themes based on one screen resolution is probably the best bet. Too bad there isn't an easy to just have one theme pack that will automatically adjust/pick the image in the bundle that best suit for the resolutions

Comment: Yep. Too bad that's not the case since there are enough images that just don't scale well..

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no glitch here, you just need to make sure the **Picture Position** is set to **Fill**.

[image]

Comment: nop, that's not what I mean. It has nothing to do with the picture position. Besides if you choose Fill, and when your wallpaper is set in really high resolutions, the theme will look awful in a netbook. parts will get cutoff, and if you choose Fit, everything will become tiny.